I'm having trouble transferring token links to my metamask address in Sepolia Testnet

Screenshot is shown below. 0.5 ETH I've got successfully, but I'm not getting the links. CAn anyone please help me with this.

If you share your testnet wallet address, I can send you some test LINK tokens on Ethereum Sepolia.
